# Criar ação em um botão html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Sou novo em desenvolvimento Web e me deparei com o seguinte problema. Tenho um input text e um botão em html e preciso criar uma ação que ao clicar no botão, uma função seja chamada e na função, irei fazer as devidas manipulações. Segue abaixo meu código.

```
<!-- FILTRO FLUTUANTE -->
    <div id="mws-themer">
        <div id="mws-themer-hide"></div>
        <div id="mws-themer-content">
            <form action="fornDetails.php">
                <div class="mws-themer-section">
                    <form action="" name="myForm" id="myForm" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" name="edtMFIR" id="edtMFIR" value="filtrar" class="mws-textinput error">
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="mws-themer-separator"></div>

                <div class="mws-themer-section">
                    <button class="mws-button red small" id="mws-themer-sendfilterPCD">Filtrar</button>           
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como resolver o problema?

Além do HTML, há códigos em php e javascript.

Comment: Você tem algum conhecimento sobre Jquery ?

Comment: Nenhum conhecimento :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito simples.

Sem Jquery:

```
    var btn= document.getElementById('id-do-botao');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 // função aqui
});
```

Com Jquery:

```
$("#id-do-botao").on("click", function(e){
    // função aqui
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Um exemplo simples para ajudar.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  alert("botao clicado");
});
```

```html
<button id="btn"> Clique aqui </button>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/botao.js"></script>

Comment: Sim, recomendo referenciar no final da pagina

Comment: Se a minha resposta está certa e te ajudou, marque-a como a certa, para me ajudar, e mostrar aos outros usuários da comunidade que a pergunta está fechada

Comment: Ainda não deu certo :/

Comment: Oque está dando errado ?

Comment: Para fins de teste, tentei fazer meu botão chamar uma pagina da internet, por exemplo, do google. var btn= document.getElementById('mws-themer-sendfilterPCD');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.location.href="http://www.google.com.br";
});

Comment: Editei a resposta, da uma olhada e tenta agora